# How to refresh a set of urls using response.setHeader() in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, refresh, response

I am using the following code to refresh the url in browser from servlet

```
String selUrl=session.getAttribute("urlsel");
response.setHeader("Refresh","10;url="+request.getContextPath+"/SiteAvailabilityServlet?urlSel=" +selUrl);
```

It is working fine.But now my problem is I want to set list of urls.

```
 String[] arr=request.getParameterValues("urlsel");
```

Gives me more than one url.
How can I pass this list to setHeader() so that multiple urls are refreshed for every 10 seconds.Please help me.How to pass it using java.